# XML config path through c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml file which the path to a particular report folder hardcoded.
eg. C:\git\ProjNew\Proj\Projects_2018\ and C:\git\ProjNew\Proj\Reports\

and xml looks like this:

```
<SampleFiles>   
        <SampleFileLocation>C:\git\ProjNew\Proj\Projects_2018\ </SampleFileLocation>    
        <ReportFileLocation>C:\git\ProjNew\Proj\Reports\</ReportFileLocation>   
    </SampleFiles>
```

when someone gets this project from git, they have to manually go to this path and make changes. In the background code, there is a lot of logic happening, is there a way to update it in c#

The c# file looks like this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "SampleFiles")]
    public class SampleFiles
    {
        public string SampleFileLocation { get; set; }
        public string ReportFileLocation { get; set; }

        public SampleFiles()
        {
            SampleFileLocation = null;
            ReportFileLocation = null;
        }
    }
```

how do i modify this code in c# so that it doesnt need to be updated by each user .

Thanks,

Comment: They only have to modify the XML so your code can work, right? Or the paths are hardcoded in your c# code?

Comment: If you are the one who defines the contents of the XML file, you should consider entering relative paths there. In the code you can take the XML file's absolute directory address as base, and `Path.Combine` the rest to it.

Comment: yes the code works when modified xml file every time, but dont want to modify it every time

Comment: I tried using getCurrent directory , and then updating the xml file, but what happens is the first run fails as it gets the old path, but from second run onwards it passes as the new path has been updated with the 1st run